# Distinction between behavior of spacetime inside a black hole during evaporation and the phase of transition to a white hoöe, in Loop Quantum Gravity

Tags: black-holes, loop-quantum-gravity, white-holes

I was just watching: Carlo Rovelli (2023). *What is a white hole?* The Royal Institution ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9VSz-hiuW9U)).

Rovelli mentions at 36 minutes that the transition to a white hole state is more likely than negligible only when the black hole has already evaporated quite a bit, and is fairly small. This could be a failing of the analogy, but I would have expected that if you jump into a black hole, you keep falling until you transition into a white hole state, and then you start being expelled out; after this "bounce" around the bottom. But if the transition only happens later after significant evaporation has occurred, is the change of the geometry during the evaporation different from the change in geometry after the transition to a white hole state, so you keep falling and something else happens when the evaporation occurs, and only after that the transition occurs, and you starting heading out. I would have expected similar kind of "shrinking" during both evaporation and after the transition into a white hole state.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the fact that no reference frame is preferred in GR.

You can describe the collapse of a star to black hole using a reference frame comoving with the star: in this frame you are "sitting" on the star as it collapses to a minimum and the geometry tunnel from black to white giving the bounce.

The same problem MUST be observed from a reference frame standing still at infinity. Such an observer never sees the star crossing the horizon. In such a case you need quantum effects to pile up to the $R=2M +\delta$ region to see a frozen star, with dimensions slightly bigger of its Schwartzschild radius, tunnel into a white hole geometry.

Such a processes needs a very long time, since the exterior region of black holes has low curvature.

Such a process is much faster when black holes evaporate a bit, since it decrease their size and increase the curvature$^1$. The tunneling has a much higher probability amplitude in this scenario, with and higher rate of transition given the fact that we now have an region with higher curvature

---

$^1$ It is true that evaporation reduce also the mass, but the Kretschmann curvature in Schwartzschild geometry goes as $K\approx m^2/r^6$ so the decrease of the radius in more important than that of the mass term

Comment: So, in some sense if you fall into a black hole you get to see the region of spacetime inside the black hole, but someone outside will not be able to see that place. Because from the outside you see stuff frozen at the horizon getting dimmer and dimmer and then after some time things come out as dark matter (as Rovelli discusses in the talk) Is that right? If that's true then black holes would give you access to otherwise undiscoverable regions of spacetime if you fall in. Even though the black hole reverses its formation, it has "secrets" behind the horizon inaccessible to outside observer.

Comment: I dont think matter comes out as dark matter. If a baryon B falls in, a baryon B tunnels out. Yes, from outside you cannot see the inside but ASSUMING that black to white hole transitions are real, then one could possibly see the inside. Of course you and me and everything alive will suffer strong tidal forces inside and horribly die, but in principle something entering then can escape IF there is a quantum geometry transition to a white hole